# MVC How to make controller inherit functions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to the .NET MVC and I was trying to implement functions I had in my previous work on WebForms. I want to extend the normal controller, so that I have a preset of functions and/or variables built in and ready for use in any controller. Is that possible or should I use a model every time I need those functions/variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a directory Infrastructure in you MVC project,

Add a class called BaseController that inherits from Controller and add your method in this class

Now, all your controller in your Controller directory should inherit from BaseController instead of Controller.